# java.lang.NullPointerException when launch spark job to a standalone cluster

Tags: apache-spark

I have the following code:

```
  val spark = SparkSession.builder
    .appName("Simple Application")
    .master("spark://myserver.com:7077")
    //.master("local[*]")   //notice this line
    .getOrCreate()

  val sc = spark.sparkContext

  val arr: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Array( 1->2 , 3 -> 4, 5 -> 4, 1->2 , 3 -> 4, 5 -> 4,7 -> 8))
  val arr2: RDD[(Int, String)] = sc.parallelize(Array( 1->"a" , 2 -> "b", 3 -> "c"))

  val map = arr2.take(arr2.count().toInt).toMap

  val result1 = arr map { case (a,b) =>
    if ( map.contains(a) ) map(a) -> b
    else "other" -> b
  }

  result1 take 100000 foreach println
```

When I launch it to `spark://myserver.com:7077` I got error:
`java.lang.NullPointerException` at line `if ( map.contains(a) ) ...`
It turns out that object `map` is null.
However when I get launch it with '.master("local[*]"', it works fine.

I launched a master and a slave at the same node.
Why I get `NullPointerException` ?

Answer (score 0):

In *cluster mode*, when you declare variables like `map` as

```
  val map = arr2.take(arr2.count().toInt).toMap
```

*It is accessible in driver node only* and it is *not mapped into each executor node when you do map function call*

```
  val result1 = arr map { case (a,b) =>
    if ( map.contains(a) ) map(a) -> b
    else "other" -> b
  }
```

So the executor nodes won't identify what *map variable* is. You will have to find a way to distribute the *map variable* to the executor nodes. One of the ways is to use as *broadcast variable* (if the data referenced by the variable is small enough) and use it inside `map` functions so that executors can call them when needed.

```
val map = sc.broadcast(arr2.take(arr2.count().toInt).toMap)

val result1 = arr map { case (a,b) =>
  if ( map.value.contains(a) ) map.value(a) -> b
  else "other" -> b
}
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: However in spark-shell with master specified as "spark://myserver.com:7077",  it works fine. Can I say that's also cluster mode?

Comment: did you try to find out how many executors are involved in both processing? In spark-shell I guess there is only one.

Comment: If you are right, does it mean I have to broadcast all variables reside in driver? E.g. val x:Int = 5, if a RDD's map use x then I have to broadcast it?

Comment: yes, if you don't have other mechanism to distributing it. Another way is to create a static object of the variables so that it can be accessed everywhere. Thats why its always better to define constants and immutables as static objects

Comment: Therefore in my case, "map" is immutable but it can never be static or constants right? So I have to broadcast it?

Comment: In your case `map` is just a immutable variable referencing to some data in memory. Yes you are right that its not a static object